# Center logo and menu on repetitive or 100% header?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML

```
<div class="mainwraper" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="header1">
        div logo left <img src="logo"> // - it sends it pasted to the left sidebar
        div class right // it send it pasted to the right sidebar 
    </div> // need to center them in the page and keep the repeative effect
    <div class="header2" style="width:100%;">
         <div class="headbar">
             <ul class="menu" style="background:#0099CC;"> … </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mainwraper {
    margin:0 auto;
}
.header1 {
    float:left; width:100%; height:78px; margin-top: 10px;
}
.header2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:auto;
    height:52px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.65;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.headbar {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.menu {
    background-color: inherit;
    background-image:url(images/menugradient.png);
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want it to look like this [1]: http://postimg.org/image/hi7knv1tp/ "tooltip"
but it looks something like this [2]: http://postimg.org/image/ptqdhlfyv/ |tooltip".
I also want to mention that after i have another Div class main wrapper of 972px that is centered correctly.

Comment: you have to set `width` for your wrapper or your `margin:0 auto;` is meaningless

Comment: @jasonslyvia It is set up in HTML <div class="mainwraper" style="width:100%;">

Comment: @Adiran `width:100%` means there is no margin for the div, so how do you expect it to be centered?

Comment: @jasonslyvia So you are saying that i need to wrap "mainwrapper" in another div?

Comment: I suggest you can add `min-width:960px` and `width:80%` for your wrapper, of course the `960px` can be any desirable value you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `margin:0 auto;` to center your navigation